# Modifying a constant variable (const)

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I came across this piece of code in which I was able to modify the value of an `const int` variable! But is this a bug or a hack? Please clarify me:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    const int a = 10;
    int* ptr = &a;

    printf("\n value at ptr is  : [%d]\n",*ptr);
    printf("\n Address pointed by ptr  : [%p]\n",(unsigned int*)ptr);

    *ptr = 11;
    printf("\n value at ptr is  : [%d]\n",*ptr);
    printf("\n %d",a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> value at ptr is  : [10]
>
> Address pointed by ptr  : [0xbf9e614c]
>
> value at ptr is  : [11]
>
> 11

Answer (score 0):

No, this is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you attempt to modify a const-qualified variable through a non-const qualifier pointer, it invokes UB.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.3, *Type qualifiers*

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a `const`-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-`const`-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.